# Not getting the expected behavior with "explicit" keyword in c++

Tags: c++, explicit-constructor

I have the following classes

```
class abc
{
private:
  string name_;
public:
  explicit abc(string name);
};

class xyz
{
private:
  abc obj_abc_;
public:
  xyz ():obj_abc_("NOTHING") { }; //I think this should give an error since explicit is used.
};
```

According to what i have understood about explicit, i should be getting a compiler error whenever xyz constructor is being called; because i am initializing the *obj_abc* by simply assigning it to a string. But i am not getting any compiler error here.
What am i missing?

Comment: `explicit abc(string name):name_(name);`  This compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explicit` on a constructor means that the constructor can't be used for conversion from its parameter type to the class type. So an implicit conversion

```
abc x = "NOTHING";
```

will be forbidden if the constructor is `explicit`, but not otherwise. An explicit conversion

```
abc x("NOTHING");
```

will be allowed in either case. In your case, direct initialisation in an initialiser list is explicit; so your explicit constructor can be used for that.

`explicit` doesn't prevent implicit conversions to the constructor parameter's type; so the conversion from `"NOTHING"` to `string` in your example is allowed in either case, using the non-explicit `string` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syntax error (use `{ }` instead of `;`) you aren't assigning or implicitly converting anything. You're explicitly constructing the object in the initialisation list.